# Javascript Module Function vs Global Function Performance

Tags: performance, closures, javascript

According to the following article, http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html, Module Functions should perform better than Global Functions because they don't have to walk backwards down the global scope chain to find the function. Functions encapsulated inside a module are in their own private scope, which would theoretically provide a considerable performance increase. I have tried to duplicate this with no success, here: http://jsperf.com/module-function-vs-global-function. Is there another method that would provide a performance increase over the use of global functions?

```
Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {

window.gvar = 5;

window.gfunc = function(x) {
  return window.gvar + x;
}

window.go = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    window.gfunc(i)
  }
}

var M = (function() {
  var me = {}, mvar = 5;

  function mfunc(x) {
    return mvar + x;
  }

  me.go = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      mfunc(i)
    }
  }

  return me;
}());

};
```

Comment: The difference in performance is almost certainly inconsequential.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the article you quote is from 5 years ago. Engines have evolved, ES6 came by... And this kind of thing sounds like micro-optimizations. I think properties access is the least of your concerns when profiling.

Comment: Well, by using `window.` you don't walk the scope chain at all, but just use a property access on the global object. Try with actual global *variables*.

Comment: Well this is just a small test for a large project restructuring. In that case, I'm not sure if this would be considered a "micro" optimization. In your opinion, since this is pre-ES6, what would be your recommendation for a Javascript Application / Library Structure for today's javascript standards? Modules, Namespace, Closure ? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other commenters that this is a micro-optimization -- it isn't something you should have to worry about unless you're in a large loop, or you're writing a framework like React.

That being said, I [modified your jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/module-function-vs-global-function/2) so that the global function test case performs a little worse. In your original, the global function was invoked as

```
window.gfunc(i)
```

and I changed it to just

```
gfunc(i)
```

Because you specified `window` in the original, there's no need to do a walk through the scope chain to find the function, so I wouldn't expect much difference there.

Comment: Well this is just a small test for a large project restructuring. In that case, I'm not sure if this would be considered a "micro" optimization. Would you recommend a Module over a Namespace or Closure? We are about to restructure and don't want to do it the improper way, again. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I would recommend that small optimization gains such as this be tackled at the end of the restructuring, preferring to focus on other aspects such as API, event spaghetti, module framework, etc. first. If you have the business justification to work on performance, then I'd suggest you do it properly by creating a performance profile and baseline to break down the performance of the app into its components and identify the slowest components. If at that point, you identify that the above code is slow because of scope chain walking, you're justified to change it. I highly doubt it, though.

Comment: The application entirely resides in the global space, all functions and all variables. There are tons, it was designed a long time ago. I need to switch to an object oriented approach, using closure or namespaces or modules. Just want to make sure I pick the right one to begin with. Thanks again.

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle, you should avoid global space, not for performance reasons but for variable name collision. Collision can be avoided using techniques such as namespacing, closures, AMD, etc. Closure techniques are fundamental to JS, and can be used in a complementary fashion to namespacing, Browserify, etc. Namespacing is inferior to AMD and Browserify but enough for most small to medium projects, IMHO.

Comment: Do you think the JavaScript Module structure, like in the article link above, is still a good way to structure a project or has it been surpassed by newer, better methods?

Comment: on Chrome the global function was 90% slower!   2ops/s for global and 18ops/s for module!    The slower global access is still fast enough, but the big difference is surprising.   Tested in Chrome 42.0.2311.135 on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: ahhh,  Now I saw the 3rd revision of the benchmark without global access to the variable where Chrome had exactly the same (high) performance to both global and local functions. So the slowness isn't related to the scope of the function but the scope of variable that was being manipulated in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The difference would be very small in modern browser because the global function window.gfunc would be cached.
See
[key advances to JavaScript performance in Windows 10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/10/09/announcing-key-advances-to-javascript-performance-in-windows-10-technical-preview.aspx)

Comment: Well this is just a small test for a large project restructuring. We are about to restructure and don't want to do it the improper way, again. Would you recommend a Module over a Namespace or Closure? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, I also don't find find any noticeable difference unless you plan to develop a really big framework or application. Another main thing that generally people use the scope for is to keep your plugin's data private and self contained from other plugins.

Comment: Well this is just a small test for a large project restructuring. We are about to restructure and don't want to do it the improper way, again. Would you recommend a Module over a Namespace or Closure? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Here's an article about some pros and cons of namespace and scopes: http://singlepageappbook.com/maintainability1.html. May be you can have some ideas when restructuring your project.